# Error: Add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()

Tags: picture-library

I want to add multiple files in Picture Library, but I am facing this error.
How can I add multiple files in Picture Library programmatically.
Here is my code:

```
Stream StreamImage = null;
if (fuImages.HasFile)
{
    StreamImage = fuImages.PostedFile.InputStream;
}

SPList list = GetListByUrl(currentWeb.Lists, "LibraryName");

if (list != null)
{
    SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fuImages.FileName, StreamImage);
    SPListItem newItem = file.Item;
    newItem.Update();
    list.Update();
}
```

Comment: Show your code, what you done so far in which you are getting error.

Comment: Here is an example of link to Upload multiple files into SharePoint library: https://rameshreddy2010.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/upload-multiple-files-into-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically-using-c/

Comment: What is the error coming at your end?

Comment: The same as i have posted in  the question